# how to have nested child route in angularjs 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Done routing for two childs ., but i want to show nested routes for those childs

for example :

```
home child1 child2 
               |
                grand child
                       |
                     grand child(1)
```

**route code**

```
{
    path: 'faqmain',
    component: FaqmainComponent,
    children: [{path: 'child-one', component: ApplicationSecondComponent}]   
  }
```

Comment: Check [this](https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-routing) or [this](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/)

Comment: hi ., i changed the question

Comment: It's the same principle downstream `children:[{path.., children:[{path, component}]}]` and so on

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this,

```
{ path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full'},

{ path:'home',component:HomeComponent},    
{ path:'parent',component: ParentComponent,
    children:[          
      { path:'',redirectTo:'child',pathMatch:'full'},
      { path:'child',component:ChildComponent, 
         children:[          
              { path:'',redirectTo:'subChild',pathMatch:'full'},
              { path:'subChild',component:SubChildComponent}
           ]
      },
 ]},
```